# Java коллекции (убрать скобки на выходе)

Tags: java

Создал коллекцию, внес данные, на выходе получаю:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Вопрос, как убрать `[]` или заменить на `()` или не учитывать?

Такое вообще реально?

Comment: А каким образом делаете вывод?

Comment: System.out.println(array);

Comment: Можно обойти массив / коллекцию в цикле и сделать вывод так, как вам нужно

Comment: мне просто желательно нужны все элементы массива в одну строку через запятую без скобок

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пусть есть коллекция:

```
List<Integer> integerList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
```

Для вывода ее содержимого без скобок:

1. Можно удалить скобки:

   ```
   System.out.println(integerList.toString().replaceAll("^\\[|\\]$", ""));
   ```
2. Можно вывести содержимое в цикле:

   ```
   for(int i=0; i<integerList.size(); i++) {
       System.out.print(i);
       if (i+1 != integerList.size()) {
           System.out.print(", ");
       }
   }
   ```
3. Можно отнаследоваться от необходимого класса и переопределить метод `toString()`.

И много чего еще можно придумать.

Comment: принял! спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

Чтобы записать в строку можно использовать String.join()

```
    String[] array = new String[] { "a", "b", "c" };
    String joined2 = String.join(",", array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно заменить скобки вот так:

```
String result = Arrays.toString(collection) // collection - ваша коллекция
     .replace("[", "")  // удалим скобку (можно заменить на "(")
     .replace("]", ""); // удалим скобку (можно заменить на ")")
```

Ну и распечатаь полученную в `result` строку:

```
System.out.println(result);
```

---

Либо пройти по коллекции и распечать каждый отдельно, без перехода на новую строку:

```
for (int index = 0; index < collection.length; index++) {
   System.out.print(collection[index] + (index != collection.length - 1 ? ", " : ""));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно проще и современней. Используйте лямбда-выражение:

```
List<Integer> array = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
array.forEach(value -> System.out.println(value));
```

Только вывод под свои нужды настройте...

Comment: А это разве в одну строку? )

Comment: поэтому и добавил коммент -> настройте вывод под свои нужды =)